# Assign variable to python list position

Tags: python-2.7

```
points = '<td class="ismCol2">.*</td>'
points_pattern = re.compile(points)
re_weekly_points = re.findall(points_pattern, htmltext)[2]
```

The code works in this format, but I'd like to assign an argument/variable to re_weekly_points.

```
value = 3
re_weekly_points = re.findall(re_weekly_points_pattern, htmltext)["%s"] %(value)
```

This is the error I receive. What is the easiest way to bypass this issue?

```
list indices must be integers, not str
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work for you to have:

`value = 3
re_weekly_points = re.findall(re_weekly_points_pattern, htmltext)[value]`

That way the indices will be integers unless `value` is not a integer.

To have something similar to lists but using strings as indices you might consider using a dictionary

Comment: @jester112358 it happens to everyone. Glad I could help